# Differences in Semantic UI Build

Tags: node.js, gulp, semantic-ui

my colleague and me are currently experiencing differences in the compiled Semantic UI files, generated on our machines, though we are based on the same sUI version.

We updated all node plugins by running  `npm update` within `/node_modules/semantic-ui/`, so we think we share the same prerequisites.

Still the builds we produce, differ a bit:

[image: Build deltas]

Can someone please give us some hint, where these differences might be resulting from?

Comment: are your OS different?

Comment: Not really. She uses Windows 7, I am running Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, Sementic UI's Gulp tasks go through a LESS converter which, in turn, uses [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer#browsers) which transforms CSS rules depending on the available browsers. Since you both have different OSes, it is possible that a different value is returned from [browserlist](https://github.com/ai/browserslist).

If there are other projects requiring the same dependencies, it may be possible that some packages satisfy the semver constraints and are not really updated since they are considered compatible. You may try and check these by globally installing [npm-check-updates](https://github.com/tjunnone/npm-check-updates) (or ncu) and run it against Sementic UI's installation.

That being said, it is hard to actually pinpoint the exact problem without more information. But I am fairly certain that this may be the case here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Meanwhile my colleagues and me have our machines been migrated to Windows 10. From now on the differences in our Semantic UI builds, described above, have gone. So I guess, they were caused by our different operating systems indeed.